# Reactjs BootstrapTable conditional column data

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table that lists car information. 
Here is my report data = [{carId:1,carName:"Honda",modelName:"Pilot",year="2020"},{carId:1,carName:"Honda",modelName:"Accord",year="2020"},{carId:1,carName:"Honda",modelName:"CRV",year="2020"}];

My report columns look like =
 const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState([{ dataField: 'carName',text: 'Car'},{dataField: 'year',text: 'Year'}]);

How do I conditionally, using BootstrapTable, print the Car Name vs Car Model in the same column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to add formatter in the column and return cell (which is carName) when the condition is met, else return row.modelName